# Problem: Fatal error worldpress theme

Tags: themes, errors

I just install a new theme in my WordPress site but im having a problem.

I can't access my page anymore. Even the WordPress dashboard.

The error message:

```
Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression 
(you can use "null !== expression" instead) in 
/home1/wavecont/public_html/wp-content/themes/sshop/inc/wc-functions.php
on line 50
```

Comment: This isn't a problem or challenge with WordPress itself, but rather an issue arising from third-party code (you can tell from the error message as it lists a file in a theme directory as the error's origin). You should contact your theme's author, since they will likely know more about their code than any of us :)

Answer (score 0):

> I cant acess my page anymore. Even the wordpress dashboard.

You have two options of varying technical difficulty.

**Option 1** - Move the theme folder to access /wp-admin/

1. Log in to your site's FTP service or control panel's File Manager
2. Navigate to `/home1/wavecont/public_html/wp-content/themes/`
3. Rename `sshops` to `sshops-moved`
4. WordPress will automatically stop using the theme's files so you can access your site
5. Submit a bug report with the theme provider

**Option 2** - Fix it yourself

Same steps as above + open `/inc/wc-functions.php` file and change line 50 to use a strict comparison with `null` (and then fix any other errors preventing your site from working).

**Recommendation** Never install untested themes or plugins on a live site - set up a local site on your computer for testing themes and plugins *before* making changes on your live site (this would give you an easily-managed environment for testing and ensure that your live site never goes down as a result of a bad theme or plugin).